# Change backcolor of shape

Tags: excel, backcolor, vba

I'm trying to update the backcolor of all of the labels that I have on a worksheet. I'd like to indicate the color using the RGB values, but I'm stuck in two places. Here is the code that I have right now:

```
Sheet2.Shapes("Label 2").Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(220, 105, 0)
```

This code will run without error, but it seems to have no effect. My label starts out white (or maybe transparent) and never changes. Can anyone tell me what I need to do to make this work? I also added this but it did nothing:

```
shp.Fill.Solid
```

Next, I'd like to capture this RGB value in a variable so that I don't have to re-type of repeatedly. Essentially, I'm looking for something like this:

```
dim col as Color
col = RGB(220,105,0)
Sheet2.Shapes("Label 2").Fill.BackColor.RGB = col
```

I know that there is no variable type called Color, but I think you can see what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 13):

Try setting the ForeColor instead:

```
Sheet2.Shapes("Label 2").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(220, 105, 0)
```

A good way to figure out what to do is to record a macro while you make the adjustment yourself. You can examine the generated code afterward and use it as a starting point.

---

Here is an example of a procedure that will add a rectangle to the activesheet, add some text to it, and then color it with your RGB values:

```
Public Sub AddRectangleWithText()
    Dim textRectangle As Shape

    Set textRectangle = ActiveSheet.Shapes & _
        .AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 10, 80, 250, 50)

    ' add your text
    textRectangle.TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Your mother was a hamster."

    ' fill the shape with the rgb color of your choice
    textRectangle.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(220, 105, 0)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I did try this earlier and got no result. I can change the height and width and a few other things. I can't do anything with colors or borders. As for recording, you can't do something like this with a mouse (I don't think), so that's not an option.

Comment: I'm wondering if labels even have a color property. I tried this with a textbox and it worked easily. I think that I'll switch to textboxes since they are basically the same thing. But I'm still open to comments if anyone has any. Thanks.

Comment: You could also use a rectangle shape instead of a label. You can set the colors, outlines, etc. easily with a shape.

Comment: Thanks. I thought of this, but rectangles don't have the ability to hold text. I'd have to layer on a textbox over every rectangle. Might be my only option. My textbox idea from above doesn't work because there is no member of Shapes for textboxes, so I can't iterate over them. This is ridiculous.

Comment: Rectangles can hold text. So can most shapes.

Comment: I added a procedure to my answer that adds a rectangle to the activesheet, adds text to it, and colors it. Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 4):

`ForeColor` actually controls the backcolor of comment/textbox(s) in Excel as follows;

- `Activecell.Comment.Shape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(240, 255, 250)
  'Mint Green`

as the `Comment`/`TextBox` `ForeColor` is a foreground fill over the Applicatoin background color.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add

```
textRectangle.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
```

in Office 2016 for

```
textRectangle.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(220, 105, 0)
```

to have an effect.